# using binary text comparison in mysql - efficiency pitfalls?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, string-comparison

I'm using [binary string comparison](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/cast-functions.html#operator_binary) on user names (defined as varchar) to be sure the string matches exactly:

```
... where binary Owner = '$user' ...
```

or

```
... from Records join Users on binary Records.Owner = Users.User ....
```

But I'm not sure if it has some (either positive or negative) impact on efficiency. [The manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/cast-functions.html#operator_binary) states:

> Note that in some contexts, if you cast an indexed column to BINARY,
>   MySQL is not able to use the index efficiently.

Is it an issue in this case? I would expect binary to be faster on the contrary, because it doesn't have to ignore case, whitespace, some accents etc.

Comment: did you check the mysql execution plan for your queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, it's possible for an expression in a WHERE clause to make it impossible to use an index on a column. You wouldn't expect an index on a float column called x to be any use for searching

```
WHERE SIN(x) BETWEEN 0.0 and 0.1
```

for example.

The answer to your problem is to define your Owner column to have a binary collation rather than a case-insensitive collation. See here for how to do that: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-column.html

Comment: thanks Ollie. What is the difference between using binary collation and using [BINARY or VARBINARY data type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/binary-varbinary.html)? Thanks, Tomas

Comment: @Tomas, the deal is this: an index for a column is organized to use the column's collation for searches.  So, if you need a case-sensitive search use a case-sensitive collation.  The `binary` operator, like other operators on the contents of a column in a search, make it likely that mySQL will have to scan the table rather than use the index.  You should run `EXPLAIN` on the query to find out for sure.

Comment: Ollie, that was a misunderstanding: in my last comment I ask: what is the difference between using binary collation (I mean by defining it columns as you recommend in your answer! not by using binary operator) and using BINARY/VARBINARY data type? Thanks

Comment: Oh, I get you now.  The BINARY data types are for binary data, not textual data. You might store image data in a BINARY type. A BINARY collation order is strictly byte-by-byte numeric.  This may be very slightly faster than case-sensitive character collation.  But the difference in speed is tiny. Don't use BINARY data types for textual data; the first time a non-ASCII character hits your system, all sorts of confusion will happen.

Comment: Thanks Ollie! So the conclusion is **to use varchar w/binary collation instead of VARBINARY in my case**. Thanks!